# How to make text appear from invisible "wall"

Tags: animation, modifiers, text-object

I tried to make similar text animiation like from game GRID 2. The text slides from vertical line but the text is cutted and theres clearly space between the line it comes out of. You can find the example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUyTZ.jpg) (the text on top left "WSR ODBYTE ZAWODY"
Unfortunately blender wouldn't let me boolean the text with invisible cube so this idea won't work. That's why I wish I could recive some help from you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a plane, give it a material with the *Shader > Holdout* node in order to make what's behind alpha transparent (also make the film transparent of course):

[image]

Other method, for Cycles only: Give your text a mix of *Transparent* and your current material, with an *Input > Light Path > Transparent Depth* as factor, and put a transparent plane in front of the text:

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok but if the text is not "Text"?

Comment: Okay nvm, it was working but I've done something and it still don't works, I decided to use your method since it's more performance friendly. The cube I used to cover the text is transparent now here's [link](https://imgur.com/a/Fg47TyN)

Comment: do you mean that it doesn't work? Do you use Cycles or Eevee? Please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I tried but the page says that it is not blender file even if it's .blend. "(also make the film transparent of course):" what does this mean? Maybe I got it wrong that's why it's not working. I use Eevee

Comment: in the Render panel > Film > enable the Transparent option so that the whole background will be transparent

Comment: It works now! But I actually wanted the background, is there any easy method to put it on? Sorry to keep you busy like that. I wonder why are even still anwsering me xD

Comment: a solution could be to put the backgound you want on a different track of the video sequencer

Comment: Are you in Eevee or Cycles? In Cycles you can give your text a mix of Transparent and your current material, with an Input > Light Path > Transparent Depth as factor, and put a transparent plane in front of the text, see my edit

Answer (score 8):

3D solution:

Add a text, convert it to mesh.

Add a box which surrounds the text as Cutter object and make it invisible in render + viewport.

Add a boolean modifier to your text with object "box".

[image]

Add another box as child to your cutter object.

result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok but if the text is not "Blender.Fun"?

Comment: then he has to take your solution of course!!!! ;)

Comment: Thank you both guys for help, you really saved me from finding it out myself :D

Comment: You are welcome